# Can you suggest a name for an energy in a magic system that incorporates the kanji 真霊?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, manga, names

I have decided to choose a more flashy and direct title for my new work. Specifically, I am creating a magic system and I have chosen the name "Rei" (霊) for it, but I don't want to offend anyone or anything. So, I have decided to follow the example of some manga and add one more kanji to the name. I have chosen "真霊" (Shinrei) and I like it. I would like to know if it is a good name, or more precisely, how can I ensure that my power system does not disrespect the meaning of the name?

Answer (score 1):

It won't offend anyone, but 真霊 would simply mean "true ghost". It doesn't look like the name of a system to the eyes of a Japanese speaker. A simple workaround is to add the suffix [-術](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jutsu), making it 真霊術 (Shinrei-jutsu). Actually, while 霊術 is not in a dictionary, it's a real word that vaguely refers to various spiritual/psychic arts in fantasy or occult contexts.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  But what is the meaning?  I don't want to create a power system with an inappropriate name.  By the way the power system is exactly the various meanings of "Rei".

Comment: By inappropriate name, I didn't mean bad or ugly name, I just meant that I want my power system to be consistent with the meaning of the name.  I think that makes it clearer

Comment: @SATORU Um, what exactly is that "system" you are talking about? Since you said "magic system", I imagined it referred to a technical system such as necromancy (降霊**術**) or alchemy (錬金**術**), but is it actually "power system"? If it's more like a power plant network, then 術 is not appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly why this type of question, I feel, is not suited for this site. The questioner could have almost anything in mind, and it can be a subjective matter whether something is an appropriate name or not. It can depend on details and context that the OP hasn't fully presented, and uncovering these through comments is not a great match for our format.

Comment: I create stories in my spare time, as a hobby.  But, I'm attracted to more complex ideas, so, when I created my story's, power system I aimed to make a name that sounded interesting.  We can say that what I mean by "system", is to create a power system for my manga-like created story.